# Calling a C# windows service function through javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, windows-services

I am working on a windows service that acts as a medium between a web application and a standalone client side program. In a nutshell: Before submitting a form on my web application, I want it to be encrypted by my client side standalone program. The medium of communication has to be the windows service.

> My question is: How do I call a C# function in my service through JS? (This function will help me relay data back and forth between the website and the standalone application)

I was successfully using an applet to act as the medium before but I have shunned that idea as many security issues are being plotted off late.

Comment: You need to encryption of the form beyond just using https?

Comment: Actually, I am working on a new social network that does not store any user sensitive data in plaintext on the server. I am thus encrypting an decrypting everything on the client side using Bouncy Castle. But that is maybe besides the point.

Comment: No, that makes sense and was what I was wondering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can self host a REST based service in a Windows Service. For example using the NancyFx framework http://nancyfx.org/. You can then make an ajax call using localhost as the endpoint, this would mean that the service MUST be installed and running on any clients which access it.

Also just a query, why are you doing your own encryption client side? You can encrypt the communications to the server using SSL and then do whatever encryption you require server side. Is this some design that is being imposed on you?

Comment: Thanks for the alternative Bigtoe. Yes I am following a given architecture. I would like to redirect you to my comment in the question!

Comment: Just beware the you'll run into cross site calling issues calling a different site from the originating site. You'll need to implement some form of CORS handling to overcome this http://enable-cors.org/

Answer (score 1):

Does it *have* to be a Windows service?

You could write a WCF service that you host inside a Windows service. There's an article on MSDN about how to do that (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733069(v=vs.110).aspx) and there are many more on the Web.

You cannot call a function defined in a Windows service directly, you have to expose it to the outside world using some kind of endpoint, like the way WCF does.

Comment: Agreed. Thanks but how will I be able to call functions from javascript even with WCF?